# Firing a scheduled task only once for certain parameters

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am wondering recently about one of the problems I encountered in my work. I need to do some actions based on the date of record in database(like the start of event), check if it started and then send some emails. The problem here is to do it only once. Since the event just starts in the background I think that CRON/Scheduler(Indatus/dispatcher in that case) is the best option to implement here as I can run the script every 5 minutes to check if some new events appear, but the real question is how would you mark that the actual action has been made on this event. I was thinking about some kind of log table with the name of action and 2 columns for parameters to hold id for which the action actually fired like

```
id    name    id_parameter_1    id_parameter_2
```

and store the records like this, but I think it may slow greatly over time when there is more records(filtering db records only by the last 5-10 minutes would help but still...). Do you have any particular experience in that matter to guide me a bit and share some thoughts ? :)

Comment: there's no need for whole new table in the database, simply add a new field for each event which you can set to `true` or `false` whether you already sent emails or not

Comment: @slash197 like I stated in the comment under the answer I'd rather like to avoid situation where I put a lot of bools like this here and there in database. I was thinking about more generic solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are gonna have only one action per event, e.g. send emails when it starts, why not just expand the event table with a flag column that marks if you sent the mail or not? That way you would avoid a JOIN with another table that would simply just hold actions.

If you have to separate it, then I would go for a table like you proposed, but then I'm not sure if you need those parameters columns, which is not that important in the end. If it's one action per one event, and one only, then I think you can safely drop the extra key (id) and just pull in the event primary key instead. You could JOIN tables with it and have things less complicated and probably quicker as you would, in a single query, pull the date from event table (assuming it is there) and pull the action from the new table as well, searching and joining by the same event index.

Just my thoughts. Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many events I'd like to fire, for now I know about two, but the number can increase. I was thinking about more generic solution for this problem to avoid adding bool markers everywhere in the future.

Comment: Then I think you need a table like you proposed and there you can just add the event key so you can join the tables. Not sure if you can get out of that any other way. You simply need a 1:n relation to that table and that's it. You could avoid having an extra id key though by merging the action name (have it as key from another ActionNames table maybe?) and event id. Not sure how you would go about efficiently joining in that case... Partition the new table maybe if it gets troublesome.

Comment: Just another though on this. Add one marker column only, make it a varchar or text if needed and create a generic hashing solution or a string that can easily be parsed using algorithm e.g. from some singleton class that would handle the parsing. Anyhow, best of luck with any solution you go for. ;)